# hide image with jquery fadeout

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I want to hide image and when image is hiding i want it hide with fadeout effect

I used this code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuza2013/nm36s05u/) but it not working

```
<button id="btn">Click me</button>

<img id="img" src="http://www.darbarg.com/Magazine/Picture/journal-29705363/4.jpg" width="300" heght="300"/>



$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#img').css('display','none').fadeOut('slow')
})
```

Comment: In the top-left-menu you have an select... choose jquery 2.1.3... without the library you can't run jquery codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.css()` in your code it quickly hide the img tag so just use `.fadeOut()` function enough

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#img').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nm36s05u/2/)

Comment: I included library but it hide fast

Comment: @YuZA remove .css()... only fadeOut() will do the job

Comment: But in your given fiddle you didn't include jquery

Comment: i fix it. then it is not necessary to use ".css" in jquery. Thanks

Comment: You may want to correct the grammar of that sentence. Your explanation is a little confusing :)

Answer (score 3):

You are setting it to invisible with css(), then fading out!

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#img').fadeOut('slow')
})
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/nm36s05u/3/

Also note: Your JSFiddle did *not* have jQuery included (there are options on the left panel of JSFiddle).